# Why is Laravel 5.4 throwing a Type error here?

Tags: events, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have this in my App\Providers\EventServiceProvider:

```
protected $listen = [
    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => [
      'App\Listeners\UserLogin'
    ],
];
```

and this in my App\Listeners\UserLogin.php:

```
use App\Events\UserLoggedIn;

class UserLogin
{
  public function handle(UserLoggedIn $event)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

but when I try to log in I get this error:

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Listeners\UserLogin::handle() must be an instance of App\Events\UserLoggedIn, instance of Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login given.
```

So can anyone tell me why I have this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `protected $listen` array is calling the wrong class.

You need to give it the name of your event class then a list of listeners.

```
protected $listen = [
   'App\Events\UserLoggedIn' => [
     'App\Listeners\UserLogin'
   ],
];
```

Comment: D'oh! I forgot to generate the event. Thank you.